# Create valid SCORM content

Tags: editor, scorm

As I am trying to develop an easy SCORM editor, which creates some SCORM content( like quizzes).
I read the four books provided by ADL, but still wasn't able to understand which are the conformance requirements or the rules which I have to take care, when I 
try to save the content from my editor as SCORM, therefor this content to be a SCORM valid content.
Is there any good description out there, which specifies exactly, how does in detail a structure looks like, which requirements are to fulfill and so on, to be the content Valid?

Manual I did it, using LMS which supports SCORM content, and check if it works, but this is not what I am looking for?

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using SCORM 1.2

Answer (score 1):

ADL has a page for SCORM 1.2. http://www.adlnet.gov/scorm/scorm-version-1-2/ ... On that SCORM 1.2 page there's also downloads of starter templates, content examples, and user guides for ISDs and content developers.

At the bottom of the page, there's a link to download the SCORM 1.2 documentation. One of the pdfs in that download is the SCORM 1.2 Conformance Requirements. I think that's what you're looking for.

For valid content, you'll need to follow the packaging rules described in the CAM book. Basically, how to zip up all the content and describe it with the manifest.xml file.

When making SCOs (a single page or lesson - generally HTML) you can refer to the RunTime Environment book for information about how a SCO communicates with the LMS, the API and the data you can get and set from the LMS.

Answer (score 0):

In SCORM 1.2 much of the spec was optional.  This means the LMS may not support all of the features.  So if you divide and conquer you don't have to take on the whole thing at once.

Valid SCORM will look up the LMS Runtime API which is literally called 'API'.  This exists in window.top, window and other locations so you need a algorithm to find it.  Your content may be launched in a IFRAME, new window, tab etc ...

Next you'll begin to interact with the Runtime, Initalizing, setting values, commiting and Terminating.

SCORM 1.2 had all the lesson status merged so your either passed, failed, completed or incomplete.  You'll need to determine which of those is more important to you.  Mainly you'll be interacting with name spaces within the CMI object the specification mentions.

But mainly you'll possibly want to set a score, a location, suspend if you want to allow the student to resume etc ...

You may do single pages, or have a frame or ajax load of external HTML/JS to act as navigation.  SCORM doesn't really supply the basis of the presentation layer, so you are left to invent that.  Could be Flash, Unity or the previously mentioned tech.

You can take what you will from my open source project which rolls back to SCORM 1.2.  Also have more info on the Wiki there.  https://github.com/cybercussion/SCOBot

GL